# JDBC query regarding column name

Tags: java, jdbc

In JDBC

```
String q = "select 'uname','pass' from user";
```

OR

```
String q = "select uname, pass from user";
```

Are `'` required for column names ??

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That should be an answer.

Comment: Why!? If you were wanting to know if they were **required**, why didn't you just try them out??

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. You definitely should not use them. Doing

```
String q="select 'uname','pass' from user";
```

would return

```
uname | pass
```

for each row in the table `user`. As in the strings `uname` and `pass`, not their value.

These are things you should try out for yourself. Play around with it, it's much more fun than asking a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a query like this :

```
select 'uname','pass' from user ;
```

It will consider `'uname','pass'` as String and it will print the value as

**`uname|pass`**

Answer (score 0):

> String q="select uname,pass from user";

is the one you're looking for